# How to keep minimum layout width to 1024 pixels while using Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created a Website design using Bootstrap 3. But I have not used .container block as the layout needs to be of 100% width. But when we re-size the browser, it should resize the layout width upto 1024 pixels only. Even on Mobile screens, the width needs to be 1024 pixels. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `min-width` CSS property and set it to 1024px. That will make sure your website is always at least 1024px wide.

Comment: Thanks Kate, I already tried that by applying on the Page wrapper I have. It does stay 1024px but the inner elements (mainly the columns) are strictly responsive on Bootstrap 3 version, so they go in the next line when we make the screen smaller

Comment: OK got it done, I just had to do col-md to col-xs, so it do not go in next line :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `row` and `span` classes then it will be responsive. That's what bootstrap does. If you don't want it to be like that then I'd recommend not using bootstrap. Unless I'm misunderstanding you.

Answer (score 0):

OK I got it done myself, I just had to do all **col-md** to **col-xs** and **min-width** of page wrapper to 1024px.